# How manage multiple push notification devices identifier for a user account in database?

Tags: php, android, ios, iphone, symfony

I'm trying to create a REST API system in PHP Symfony2 for a website and apps for iOS, Android and Windows Phone.

I'm actually thinking about the database table for the devices of the user, because he may have multiple devices.

So, my solution for now is to create an array of devices for the user. The device table contain the type of the device (iPhone, iPad, Nexus, Nokia, etc), the device push identifier, the OS (iOS, Android, Windows Phone), and the user id.

But I don't know if is the good way, so what do you think ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's a good approach, but I'm not sure whether it is important to keep track of the Device Type?

My approach would be:

```
User (table)
    UserId
    UserName
    ...

Devices (table)
    OSType
    DevicePushId
    UserId
```

You would only need to know the OS type since each OS handles notifications differently. But knowing whether the device is an iPad vs iPhone is not as important unless you are going to be sending different types of notifications/content dependent on whether they have a phone or a tablet.

Comment: I think now that there is a problem in this solution, the push identifier (in iOS for exemple) can be updated for the device, so I think the device type is necessary for the system and update him if the device push id is updated, no ?

Comment: Android's GCM also sometimes updates the push id. You only need to know the original id to update it. For example: original id = 123456, iOS/Android notifies you that the id has expired and/or has been updated and then gives you the new id. All you have to do is do a search on the table to find the original id for the user and replace it with the new one.

Comment: It should be perfectly fine to have multiple push ids for the same OSType since it should represent different devices so you could have a table with:

iOS, 123456, 1;
iOS, 567891, 1;
iOS, 734545, 1;
Android, 345345, 1;
Android, 435231, 1;
Windows, 634545, 1;

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I write the code now for create the system! :-)